# TCP connection stuck in SYN_RECV state despite ACK received

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, connection, syn

My client and server are both internal machines.  tcpdump on both client and server show all three parts of handshake are communicated, however netstat on server shows SYN_RECV, and on client shows ESTABLISHED.  The server keeps sending a syn-ack as though it never received the client's ack.

Below is a link showing:

- Server tcpdump (jbod-bubbles)
- Server netstat showing SYN_RECV
- Client tcpdump (mrnobody)
- Client netstat showing ESTABLISHED

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfOTf.jpg

Comment: Interesting, do you have iptables running ? Did you make sure none of the IPs are mounted twice and that there's no duplicate mac address ?

Comment: Misconfigured firewall on server (only allowing syn but not other packets)